# Well ordering on sequences over well-ordered sets

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

I'm trying to solve problem 4.4.8 of Hrbacek & Jech's *Introduction to Set Theory*.  The problem reads in part,

> Let $(A,<)$ be linearly ordered.  Define $\prec$ on $\operatorname{Seq}(A)$ by: $\langle a_0, \dots, a_{m-1} \rangle \prec \langle b_0, \dots, b_{n-1} \rangle$ if and only if there is $k < n$ such that $a_i = b_i$ for all $i < k$ and either $a_k < b_k$ or $a_k$ is undefined (i.e. $k = m < n$)... If $(A, <)$ is well-ordered, $(\operatorname{Seq}(A), \prec)$ is also well-ordered.

This looks to me like the lexicographic ordering of dictionary words, where a finite sequence that extends a shorter sequence comes after in the ordering.  But then the sequence of strings $ab > aab > aaab > \cdots$ is an infinite decreasing sequence of words in $\operatorname{Seq}(A)$, which I think proves that $\operatorname{Seq}(A)$ cannot be a well ordering.

I must be making a simple mistake here, but in two days I haven't managed to find it!  Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, and there is an error in the definition of $\prec$ that you have written.  The definition of $\prec$ should instead require $a_i=b_i$ for all $i\color{red}>k$ (meaning that for each $i>k$, either $a_i$ and $b_i$ are both defined and equal or they are both undefined).  That is, you should use the *reverse* lexicographic order, where you start from the *end* of the sequence instead of the beginning.  (Note in particular that if $n>m$ then always $\langle a_0, \dots, a_{m-1} \rangle \prec \langle b_0, \dots, b_{n-1} \rangle$ by taking $k=n-1$.)